# How to open Application with some intervals when app closed in android?

Tags: android, service

I want to open my application automatically with some intervals if user destroy my application.How can i create this.I don't know how to create this Please anybody help me..

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: don't you think what you are trying to do is irritating for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// Replace MyActivity.class with the activity class you want to run periodically
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long interval = 60 * 60 * 1000;  // one hour

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now, interval, pi);
```

Also, add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, Use background service.
from service you can start your application as required.

use this from service

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

for service reference
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use alarm manager (AM) or GCM. With AM you can set timer and start your app in some interval. Via GCM you can send notifications from your server and run some actions.

Using service isnt a good idea. AM and GCM is more reliable way. I think AM is what you need.

P.S. Dont do it. Users will curse you )

Comment: GCM is an overkill, it'd require connectivity and isn't always reliable to be delivered at the exact specified time (a.k.a. known bug with not delivering messages from time to time). AlarmManager is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, GCM is quite comlicated. If interval is quite small (once/several times a day) than imho AM, but if interval is about a week than GCM is a nice alternative way to do this.